# How can I dynamically set the height of an MvxListView upon adding a list item?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have an MvxListView that I'm populating by clicking an "Add" button, which functions fine. The problem is that the list view's height needs to expand when I add an item. I've tried setting 
android:layout_height="wrap_content", but that doesn't seem to work. Here's the code for the button and list:

```
<Button
        android:text="Add One"
        local:MvxBind="Click AddSomething" />
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_template"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ProjectModel.Something" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do makes that much sense...

If you want the list to grow beyond the current screen-height, then use a non-zero size initially - e.g. use  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` or `android:layout_height="200dp"` initially - the list will then grow and will eventually scroll as the list contents get long enough to cause overflow.

If you really want a control that changes size as items are added, then you can use `MvxLinearLayout` instead - but beware that if the list gets large then:

- this will not scroll (you can help it scroll using a ScrollView but then you have to provide that with a size initially too)
- this LinearLayout will not be very efficient (it won't reuse cells in the same way as ListView does).

If you really want a ListView that dynamically sizes, then you can probably do something like inheriting from `MvxListView`, and you can then intercept when child views get added to work out and set the new height using SetLayoutParams- but I'm not sure that this will be that great a UX.

Comment: Yes, that's eventually the path we went with.